# Where pull request fits into release pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, terraform, cicd, infrastructure-as-code

I'm creating a multi-stage pipeline in Azure DevOps to deploy infrastructure as code via Terraform and have a question about when in the release process a pull request should occur...

My pipeline has a CI stage that does a terraform validate, some testing etc. and then individual stages to deploy to each environment in turn.

When I create a PR, the pipeline is triggered which runs the CI and dev deployment stages. Passing of these stages is required before closing the PR and merging into main.

Does that strategy sound correct? I'm used to application deployment pipelines where creation of a PR might trigger a deployment into test to run automated tests as a condition of the PR. In an IaC pipeline, this doesn't seem to make sense though because deploying through to test doesn't prove anything more than deploying into dev given that there aren't any additional tests run in the test env.

Bit confused and would like to make sure my thinking is not flawed! Experience of others in similar scenarios would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy seems fine to me, however, I'd suggest you add a test stage using [Terratest](https://terratest.gruntwork.io/) as part of your CI process so you can define specific use cases to verify that the infrastructure deployed meets your needs, this would make it similar to application deployment pipelines.